# Pneumatic circuit drawing software for Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, drawing

I want to do some drawing such as this one which represents a pneumatic (compressed gas) circuit.

[image]

I have found [SMC's Pneumatic Circuit Design Software](https://www.smc.eu/portal_ssl/webpages/00_local/cee/products/engineering_tools/pneu_draw.jsp) but it doesn't seem to run with Linux.

[FluidDraw](http://www.festo.com/net/SupportForum/yaf_postst383_FluidDraw---Computer-Specifications.aspx) as well, runs only with Windows, apparently.

Anything before trying to run them through Wine?

Comment: Did you ask SMC? Did you try running the Windows program with WINE (WINdows Emulator) in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Dia, which is free, open source, and multiplatform including [Linux](http://dia-installer.de/download/linux.html). It is often compared to Microsoft Visio.

It comes with [pneumatic shapes](http://dia-installer.de/shapes/Pneumatic/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any of the available software, compatible with Linux or even mac OS. MS Viso, FESTO FluiDraw, SMC PneuDraw, Scheme editor, EZ Schematics .. all are only Windows.

I think your best bet is to download already available vector pneumatic symbols, for example from [here](https://www.smc.eu/portal_ssl/webpages/01_products/engineering_tools/pneumatic_symbols/pneumatic_symbols.jsp) . And then use vector graphics application to make the drawing you want. The best vector graphic software I know is Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

actually, SMC's [Pneumatic Design Software](https://www.smc.eu/portal_ssl/webpages/00_local/cee/products/engineering_tools/pneu_draw.jsp) does work with linux, although this requires [wine](https://winehq.com) and winetricks.

If you did not use wine before, use `WINEARCH=win32 winetricks jet40` to initialize a 32bit wine installation in your home folder, including the winetrick jet40.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Hopsan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopsan). It is mainly a simulation software though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).